# Ruby - How do I escape both a back to back backslash and a single

Tags: ruby, encoding

I have the following string, `\'e4`, which I can't seem to get printed to my IRB console.

My attempts:

1. `"\'e4"` gives me back `"'e4"`
2. `"\\'e4"` gives me back `"\\'e4"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-quoted strings will always show up with double backslashes in `irb` due to the way they're escaped.

If you want to see what it actually is:

```
puts "\\'e4"
# => \'e4
```

Your first attempt is read as "literal quote e 4" and the second is "literal backslash quote e 4". The second one is correct regardless of how it's displayed.